# ImportError: cannot import name 'sysconfig' on python

Tags: xubuntu, 18.10

```
pip3 -V
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from pip.utils import get_installed_distributions, get_prog
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pip.locations import (
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/locations.py", line 9, in <module>
    from distutils import sysconfig
ImportError: cannot import name 'sysconfig'
```

Answer (score 10):

It seems your Python installation was incomplete/broken, launch your terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and run following command:

```
sudo apt install python3-distutils
```

This will install the required package to fix the error, as you can see on your error output.

Source: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5356

Answer (score 1):

After upgrading ubuntu 18 -> 19 got the same.
The problem was that I was using virtual environment created on 18 but globally python was reinstalled.
In order to fix it:

1. remove old virtual environment.
2. create new one
3. install requirements.

In my case that was that.